# How to perform binding with programmation

Tags: wpf, vb.net, binding

I know it's not really the best way to do it, but I have a special occasion when I would need to add new columns to a datagrid using code and apply a binding to it to

For example, I got this :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="GridUtilisateurs" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource BaseGrid}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Canvas Background="{Binding ColorActive}"></Canvas>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Usager" Width="*"  MinWidth="50"
                                               Binding="{Binding UserName}"                                               
                                               IsReadOnly="True" />
                 </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

How can I do the same thing, but with code ? The main problem I have is with the binding, all the rest seems fine.

This is what I got so far, but I can't make the binding work. The binding 'path' I would have use in XAML is equivalent to oCol.ColumnName :

```
            Dim oNewColumn As DataGridColumn
            Dim oBinding As New System.Windows.Data.Binding

            Select Case oCol.DataType

                Case GetType(Boolean)
                    oNewColumn = New DataGridCheckBoxColumn()
                    oNewColumn.MinWidth = 25
                    CType(oNewColumn, DataGridCheckBoxColumn).IsThreeState = False
                    CType(oNewColumn, DataGridCheckBoxColumn).Binding = oBinding
                    oNewColumn.Width = System.Windows.Controls.DataGridLength.SizeToHeader
                Case Else
                    oNewColumn = New DataGridTextColumn()
                    oNewColumn.MinWidth = 50
                    oNewColumn.Width = New System.Windows.Controls.DataGridLength(1, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridLengthUnitType.Star)
                    CType(oNewColumn, DataGridTextColumn).Binding = oBinding
            End Select
            oNewColumn.Header = oCol.ColumnName

            GridData.Columns.Add(oNewColumn)
        Next

        GridData.ItemsSource = MyList
```

After a while, I finally got to understand what's wrong. I needed to use [Description] because I was given a datetable. Now that this is done, I have another problem though. Since sometime I need to have dates, I would need to use a DataTemplateColumn and I tried using one but I can't really make one work so far. Anyone knows how to do it ?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim oNewColumn As DataGridColumn
            Dim oBinding As New System.Windows.Data.Binding

        Select Case oCol.DataType

            Case GetType(Boolean)
                oNewColumn = New DataGridCheckBoxColumn()
                oNewColumn.MinWidth = 25
                CType(oNewColumn, DataGridCheckBoxColumn).IsThreeState = False
                oBinding.Path ="PathName1"
                CType(oNewColumn, DataGridCheckBoxColumn).Binding = oBinding
                oNewColumn.Width = System.Windows.Controls.DataGridLength.SizeToHeader
            Case Else
                oNewColumn = New DataGridTextColumn()
                oNewColumn.MinWidth = 50
                oNewColumn.Width = New System.Windows.Controls.DataGridLength(1,             System.Windows.Controls.DataGridLengthUnitType.Star)
                oBinding.Path="PathName2"
                CType(oNewColumn, DataGridTextColumn).Binding = oBinding
        End Select
        oNewColumn.Header = oCol.ColumnName

        GridData.Columns.Add(oNewColumn)
    Next

    GridData.ItemsSource = MyList
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work although now I knwo why (I needed to use [PathName1] instead because of the structure I was given.

Comment: when you created oBinding  you not set path for new  binding object.

Comment: can you write this in c# (please)?

Comment: I know I didn't in this example, becauase I tried it and it didn't work at first.

Comment: Sure, I am trying to create a dynamic grid generator for some tables we have in our database. Depending of the name, the type and other criterion, I want to be able determine the type of column to use. It's not a simple as saying varchar are text and int are combo or other stuffs like that. It depends of the foreign keys too. In other words, autogeneratecolumns doesn't work for me. It works fine for now except for datetime and the fact that I have to double-click to open a combo box